# How to delete a child node including nested child nodes in Firebase Cloud Functions?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I'm using Firebase Cloud Functions to delete a child node when the event is expired and all the values get removed except a nested child node it doesn't get removed

what's the issue and how to fix it?

```
exports.removeOldMessages = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    const messagesRef = admin.database().ref('events')
    messagesRef.once('value', (snapshot) => {
        snapshot.forEach((child) => {
            child.forEach((child) => {
                if (Number(child.val()['endDate']) <= new Date().getTime()) {
                   child.ref.set(null)
              }
            })
        })
    })
    return res.status(200).end()
})
```

here is the JSON

```
{   "events" : { "N5iTuYzAbJa02RauxCl3uh2Nggz1" : {  
"-LNmIvSdrwK96KCGcmXm" : {
    "addedBy" : "Riyadh Figures",
    "coordinate" : [ 24.70914690943994, 46.78851541131735 ],
    "endDate" : "1538442801.0",
    "imagePath" : "-LNmIvSdrwK96KCGcmXm",
    "key" : "-LNmIvSdrwK96KCGcmXm",
    "title" : "hjihgf",
    "userPicture" : "N5iTuYzAbJa02RauxCl3uh2Nggz1"   } }
```

Comment: Please edit the question to explain what you expect the function to do.  Also, why are you not just querying for only the children to delete?  Querying everything and filtering on in the function is potentially slow an expensive.

Comment: @DougStevenson the function should delete a child when it's "endDate" timestamp is equal to or less than the current timestamp, when the time comes it deletes all the children except the "coordinate" child. Also how would I go on about doing that using a query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand what you're trying to achieve, by far you want to delete the event node if it's expired. Try it like below

```
var deleteObj ={}
messagesRef.once('value', (snapshot) => {
    snapshot.forEach((childSnap) => {
        childSnap.forEach((innerChild) => {
            if (Number(innerChild.val()['endDate']) <= new Date().getTime()) {
      // you can do this in two ways
      // step 1: Direct Deleting
               admin.database().ref('/events/' + childSnap.key + '/' + innerChild.key).set({}); 
      // step 2: Pass into Object
              deleteObj['/events/' + childSnap.key + '/' + innerChild.key] = null;
     // As you asked for deleting coordinate
             deleteObj['/events/' + childSnap.key + '/' + innerChild.key +'/' + 'coordinate']  = [] or {}; // this will do
          }
        })
    })
})

   if(deleteObj) // Step 2 
       admin.database().ref().update(deleteObj).then(function(){
           // console.log("Deleted");
       })
```

Step 2 will be helpful if you have more than one nodes to delete as fb support multipath update or delete

Keep one thing, as Doug said in your question comment. Why you have download entire data to delete some nodes alone.

Comment: Thank you! I want child "coordinate" to be deleted along with the other children in the expired node. because it's the only child that doesn't get deleted in my code. Can you show me how to use queries to delete expired events?

Comment: Thank you so much!!! I would love to delete the expired nodes using queries if you could show me :)

Comment: seriously I'm not understanding man. For example edit your question and highlight which node i.e (entire node or child keys) you want to delete.

Comment: Basically, I want to remove the entire event node once it expires (including all the children of that expired event node). I hope I'm making sense now.

Comment: the functions runs each minute and compares the "endDate" with the current time in JavaScript and once the current time passes "endDate" it deletes that event node including any children under that event.

Comment: Ohh. If I have to tell you what I understood is that you want to delete the event node i.e N5iTuYzAbJa02RauxCl3uh2Nggz1 considering this node event is expired if you want to do this try like  admin.database().ref('/events/' + childSnap.key).set({});

Comment: @MuruGan can you take a look my question

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53355262/how-to-manipulate-firebase-snapshot-data